how to use Gauss Multiplication Formula for Gamma function?
I studied Gauss Multiplication Formula which known for $n\in \Bbb Z^+ \wedge nx\notin \Bbb Z^-\cup\{0\}$
$$\Gamma(nz)=(2\pi)^{(1-n)/2}n^{nz-(1/2)}\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\Gamma\left(z+\frac{k}{n}\right)$$
but I didn't understand how to use it for example by putting $z=\frac{1}{2} , n=2$ then
$$ \prod_{k=0}^1\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{k}{2}\right)=\sqrt{\pi}$$
but this don't give a new formula since we can get it by Reflection formula for Gamma function
but if we put $z=\frac{1}{3} , n=4$ then we can find that
$$ \Gamma\left(\frac{7}{12}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{13}{12}\right)=\frac{\pi\sqrt{\pi}}{3\sqrt[6]{2}}$$
So my question how to find useful values for $n,z$ to find a new formula using Gauss Multiplication Formula?
there are a lot of examples that I didnt understand how to find correct values of $n,z$ for example how to prove
$$ \Gamma^2\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{7}{12}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{11}{12}\right)=\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt[4]{3}} \pi^2$$
